# Google GCE Hosted Instance Group Setup Issue

Tags: gcloud, server-setup

Is there a way for Managed Instance Group (MIG) to force a VM to be retained without being replaced and re-created?

Ispconfig is currently used to manage websites within a VM instance
But it also needs load balancing to deal with burst traffic
If you use a hosted instance group,
But as long as the VM load is too high and unresponsive, it will be re-established and replaced
Have tried adding a new disk to the VM and storing MySQL and website files in it
Automatic creation of hosted instance groups through templates
But the Google template cable has a disk that can only be read but cannot be written

Is there any other better practice?

Answer (score 0):

> But the Google template cable has a disk that can only be read but
>   cannot be written

MIGs are for stateless, instances will be deleted and created as needed. Remove databases from managed instance groups, and put them on separate single instances (or Cloud SQL).

Review the [autoheal status of instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#viewing_current_actions_on_instances). See if any timeout or are otherwise unhealthy.

Find why instances are unhealthy. Review the configuration of the checks for the correct port, timeout, and a few rechecks. Check firewall rules. Check the health port is listening manually (perhaps with `curl` or `nmap`). Check performance, that the host is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Managed instance groups contain one or more vm instances that are created by using an instance template. In order to update instances in a MIG you can make update requests to the group as a whole, using the MIG Updater feature.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups

An MIG Updater helps you  deploy new versions of software to instances in your managed instance groups, at the same time controlling the speed of deployment, the level of disruption to your service, and the scope of the update.

As John stated in his post, MIGs are are for stateless apps that don’t depend on specific state of the underlying VM instances to run.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#stateless